# angular2-mdl table component with server side data

Tags: rest, angular, angular2-mdl

I experiment with [Angular 2 - Material Design Lite](http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/) especially with the table component but I can not figure out how would I pass data from server on ajax request. [Here](http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/table) is the example provided for table initialisation.
How would I pass data from restAPI to table component?

Answer (score 2):

Here I have a kind of working example. I placed the initial data on my Component Init method where I call the DataService which populates the table. I'm not sure if is the right workaround but at this point I have data in table.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogConfig, MdIcon } from "@angular/material";
import { AuthenticationService, DialogsService, DataService } from '../../../services/';
import { RouterModule, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';
import {
    IMdlTableModelItem,
    MdlDefaultTableModel
} from 'angular2-mdl';


export interface ITableItem extends IMdlTableModelItem {
    username: string;
    email: string;
    role: string;
    unitPrice: number;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'employees',
    templateUrl: 'app/layouts/secure/employees/employees.html',
    providers: [DialogsService, MdIcon]
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
    public message: string;
    public employees: any[];
    public result: any;
    public showSearchBar: false;
    public tableData:[ITableItem];
    public selected;

    public tableModel = new MdlDefaultTableModel([
        {key:'username', name:'Username', sortable:true},
        {key:'email', name:'Email', sortable:true},
        {key:'role', name:'Role', sortable:true},
        {key:'status', name:'Status', sortable:true},
        {key:'unitPrice', name:'Test', numeric:true}
    ]);

    constructor(
        private dialogsService: DialogsService,
        public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private _dataService : DataService,
        private router: Router
    ) {
    }
    openDialog() {
        this.dialogsService
            .confirm('User Form', 'Are you sure you want to do this?', this.viewContainerRef)
            .subscribe(res => this.result = res);
    }

    toggleSearch() {
        console.log(this)
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        var self = this;
        this._dataService
            .GetAll('employees')
            .subscribe( data => {
                    data = Object.keys(data).map((key)=>{ return data[key]})
                    this.employees = data;
                    this.tableData  = data;
                    this.tableModel.addAll(this.tableData);

            }, error => console.log(error),
                () => function ( data ) {
                    this.tableData  = this.employees;
                    this.tableModel.addAll(this.tableData);
                    this.selected = this.tableData.filter( data => data.selected);
                },
            );
    }
    generateArray(obj){
        return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return obj[key]});
    }

    selectionChanged($event){
        this.selected = $event.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@fefe made it a little more difficult than it had to be, at least with the current version.  The magic of the **as** keyword can do the heavy lifting.

For example my class setup looks like:

```
import...

export interface IUnreadMessage extends IMdlTableModelItem {
    messageId: number;
    subject: string;
    from: string;
}

@Component ...

export class ...
    private unreadMessagesTable = new MdlDefaultTableModel([
        {key: 'messageId', name: 'Message ID'},
        {key: 'subject', name: 'Subject'},
        {key: 'from', name: 'From'}
    ]);
```

Then in my ajax call I have:

```
 ...ajax call here).subscribe(value => {
    const messages = value as Array<IUnreadMessage>;
    this.unreadMessagesTable.addAll(messages);
  },
  error => {
    ...error handler here...
  });
```

Make sure your interface is EXACTLY (including case) the same as your returned ajax data and it should hook right up!